# baseUrl per path in require.js

Tags: requirejs

Is there anyway to set the baseUrl at the path level? I have 1 dependency (my-dependency) in a different folder than the other dependencies. However, when I set the path for that 1 dependency, any dependency that my-dependency has, is relative to the baseUrl of the main app, and not to my-dependency.

I'm looking for something like this maybe:

```
require.config(
    baseUrl: '/js/ad-buys',
    paths: {
        "my-dependency": {
            path: "/js/contacts/my-dependency"
            baseUrl: "/js/contacts"
        }
    }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

No, that's not possible.

You should not need it anyway. What you describe wanting to do should be achievable by using relative paths for your dependencies. For instance, `my-dependency` could contain:

```
define(['./foo'], function (foo) {
});
```

This would load the module `/js/contacts/foo` and bind it to the `foo` parameter of your function . You can also use `..` if you need to move up the hierarchy.